# Colombia: financial requirements for tourists seem excessive

Tags: visas, south-african-citizens, colombia

I am a South African citizen and last year I traveled to Colombia for tourism. As a South African, I needed a visa. I am planning another visit but since October this year the [rules have changed](https://www.cancilleria.gov.co/sites/default/files/5477%20del%2022%20de%20julio%20de%202022%20%281%29.pdf). Turns out, there is a specific new rule for any person wanting to enter as a tourist (and who is not exempt such as Europeans or North Americans). This rule states each tourist has to:

> Acreditar solvencia económica del solicitante y/o de la persona
> natural que formula la invitación mediante extractos bancarios
> correspondientes a los seis (6) meses previos a la solicitud, que
> demuestran ingresos mensuales no inferiores a diez (10) salarios
> minimos legales mensuales vigentes (SMLMV).

Translated:

> Show evidence of economic solvency of the applicant and/or of the
> natural person making the invitation through bank statements
> corresponding to the six (6) months prior to the application, which
> demonstrate monthly income of not less than ten (10) legal monthly
> minimum wages in force (SMLMV).

In other word, every individual tourist needs to show that they had an income that is 10x the minimum wage for each of the past 6 months. Minimum wage is [COP 1 million](https://www.salariominimocolombia.net/) at the moment, so 10x that is R36,000 (EUR 1980). In South Africa, few people earn this kind of (post-tax) monthly salary. There will be very few households where every member makes this kind of money. And people such as retirees don't have a monthly salary. And basically anybody who has savings but not a fixed income for the past 6 months.

I am well off by South African standards and can afford a holiday to Colombia. However, I can't meet these standards, much less my spouse who studies. Last year we qualified for a visa but I don't understand how these rules are supposed to work. Am I misinterpreting the numbers? Am I overseeing a loophole? I have been able to get a Schengen visa without a problem but it seems impossible for me and many other South Africans to visit Colombia. Given the price levels in Europe vs Colombia, I can't imagine that this is how it is supposed to be so I hope someone can prove me wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately Visa rules don't have to make sense. I recently planned a short trip to India but it turned out even with two "good" passports (US and Germany) you actually need a personal reference from someone in India. So if you don't know someone in India (yet) you can't go. The unofficial workaround in this case, is to book a hotel and the hotel manager will give the reference. That was too complicated for me: we went to Mauritius instead :-)

Comment: There’s something weird in that regulation: if you apply for a digital nomad visa then the requirement is “only” 3 times minimum wages. Did you check for subsequent updates/amendments which may have lowered the bar?

Comment: @jcaron There hasn't been any resolutions ([list](https://www.cancilleria.gov.co/resoluciones-generales-expedidas)) on visa matter since 5477. And that difference sounds normal, the salary that would be needed to live in Colombia is widely different than in other countries, as you live there you *only need* 3x, as a tourist, they make sure that you are actually going to leave and having the money to leave by all means but 10x is extremely excessive